# Python в windows  7 x64

Tags: python, windows

Что нужно сделать, что бы был установлен питон и среда для его разработки? ( Что  скачать, где скачать, какую среду выбрать?)

1. Выбор пал на visual studio 2010 + python
2. sublime text 2

Но как поставить сам питон в винде 7 (х64)? И лучше сразу 2 и 3 версии.

Да кстати, на какой лучше писать/учить?

Заранее спасибо за советы. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Питон и 2-ой, и 3-ей версии могут стоять вместе (в разных директориях, естественно). Единственная небольшая проблема это то, какой из них будет запускаться командой `python`, но это решается через установку значения переменной окружения `PATH`.

Скачать можно здесь: [Download Python](http://python.org/download/). Берите, например, вот это (номера версий могут поменяться - берите последние):

- Python 2.7.3 Windows X86-64 Installer
- Python 3.2.3 Windows X86-64 MSI Installer

> Да кстати, на какой лучше
> писать/учить?

Дам сугубо субъективный ответ - есть смысл брать сразу третий. Правда, бОльшая часть написанных кодов совместима со второй версией, а не с третьей. Но думаю, это временное явление.

К вопросу о среде - мне удобнее Sublime Text 2 + консоль. Кому-то будет удобнее VS2010 + PTVS или Eclipse - выбирайте сами по личным предпочтениям.

Comment: Спасибо за столь развернутый ответ.

Sublime Text 2 + консоль? А для чего вы консоль используете?

Comment: @Tim, Sublime использую чисто как редактор, консоль - для исполнения скриптов.

Answer (score 4):

1. Для начала нужно поставить
       интерпретатор Python (для изучения
       подойдет любая версия 2 или 3),
       просто под 3 версию еще не все
       библиотеки портированы. Так что писать лучше на 2, ИМХО.
2. В качестве среды IDE порекомендовал бы использовать PyCharm (платная, есть триал). Sublime text2 тоже не плохая вещь.
3. В винде 64 легко ставится 32х питон
4. Можно ставить сразу две версии питона. В среде просто нужно выбрать исполняющий интерпретатор

Comment: @Anovoselof А не подскажите литературу по питону 3.2?

Comment: По 3 версии не могу сказать. По 2 версии Марк Лутц

Comment: 1. Лутц "Изучаем Python" - книга интересна тем, что описываются сразу Python 2 и 3 и приводятся отличия. Очень хорошая книга, но очень пухлая и слишком много слов, что иногда достает. Но при этом много интересных нюансов и пр. Для профессионального начала - самое оно.

2. Специально по Python3 - Саммерфильд "Python3"